# Inequalities on norms

Tags: real-analysis

$C[0, 1]$

(a) Show that $\|f\|_2 ≤ \|f\|_∞.$

(b) Find a sequence of functions $(f_N)$ satisfying $\|f_N\|_2 → 0$ and $\|f_N\|_∞ → ∞ $ as $N → ∞$.

(c) Show that $\|f\|_1 ≤ \|f\|_2$

(d) Find a sequence of functions $(f_N)$ satisfying $\|f_N\|_1 → 0$ and $\|f_N\|_2 → ∞$ as $N → ∞$.

I'm sure that all of these questions are not that challenging, and I have the definitions of $\|f\|_2$ and $ \|f\|_∞.$ and can see that it is obvious, but I'm unsure on how to actually show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b) Let $f_n(t) = \sqrt n t^{n^2}.$ Then

$$\int_0^1 f_n^2(t)\,dt = \int_0^1 nt^{2n^2}\,dt = \frac{n}{2n^2+1} \to 0.$$

But $\|f_n\|_\infty \ge f_n(1-1/n^2)=\sqrt n (1-1/n^2)^{n^2} \to \infty.$

d) An example of this is

$$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{[\ln(1+1/n)]^{1/4}(x+1/n)^{1/2}}.$$

Comment: (b): Is there a particular reason you use $t^{n^2}$ and not just $t^n$?

Comment: Don't you also have to take the square root of the integral to find $||f_n||_2$?

Comment: @AnoUser1 If $\int f_n^2 \to 0,$ then so does $\|f_n\|_2.$

Comment: I agree and tried to edit the comment but it didn't let me. Was just making sure!

Comment: How did you find the function for d?

Comment: I thought of this: $1/\sqrt x \in L^1,$ but not in $L^2.$ But this function is not continuous, so I have to shop for a continuous example that's sort of like $1/\sqrt x.$ How about $f_n(x) =1/\sqrt {x+1/n}?$ These $f_n$ are continuous. Then I played around and modified  a bit to get $\|f_n\|_1\to 0$ while $\|f_n\|_2\to \infty.$

Answer (score 1):

(a) Start with $\|f\|_2^2 = \int_0^1 |f|^2$ and bound the integrand by $\|f\|_\infty^2$.

(b) $\|f_N\|_\infty \to \infty$ means the maximum value of $f_N$ grows to infinity. But for $\|f_N\|_2 \to 0$ to happen, the places where $f_N$ is large must be on a set of small measure. So a sequence of "tent" or "spike" functions whose peaks grow taller and taller but whose support gets smaller and smaller probably would work.

(c) Use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

(d) Use a similar approach as in (b). If it helps, play around with step functions first until you find a working example; then "smooth" them out into functions in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: I've been trying to find a function for d for ages, and have had no luck. Any help appreciated.